# Need help on merging two data.frames correctly

Tags: r, csv

I need help on merging two `data.frame`s correctly!

What I'm gonna do first is importing a CSV with three Columns ("Startmeter","Endmeter","Information")

Then I want to give out a simple Sequence from 0 to 40000 Meters altogether with the existing Data from the CSV. It would be fine, if somebody could help :)

=== First Data.Frame (simple Sequence)

```
Meter
87
88
89
90
91
92
93
94
95
96
```

=== Second Data.Frame (CSV Data)

```
Meter        Information

90           1
91           1
92           1
93           1
101          2
102          2
103          2
```

=== Final Product (How it should look like)

```
Meter        Information

88           NA
89           NA
90           1
91           1
92           1
93           1
94           NA
95           NA
96           NA
97           NA
98           NA
99           NA
100          NA
101          2
102          2
103          2
104          NA
105          NA
....
```

How my Code looks so far:

```
csvlesen<-read.csv("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop\\R\\File.csv",header = TRUE, sep = ";", quote="", dec=",")

lastmeter<- csvlesen[nrow(csvlesen),2]*1000  
startmeter <- csvlesen[ ,1]*1000
endmeter <- csvlesen[ ,2]*1000      
information<- csvlesen[ ,16]

d <- data.frame()
e <- data.frame(0:lastmeter)
colnames(e) <- c("Meter")  

for (i in 1:lastmeter) { 
  m <-seq(startmeter[i],endmeter[i])
  m_final <- head(m, -1) 
  csvmeter <- cbind(m_final,information[i])  
  colnames(csvmeter) <- c("Meter","Information")  
  d <- rbind(d,csvmeter)   
}
```

Comment: Did you try `?merge`.e.g.: `merge(df1,df2,all.x=TRUE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do something like the following using `merge`.
First, we create some toy data, and then we use `merge` to merge the `data.frame`s into one.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Meter = 41:50)
df1
#   Meter
#1     41
#2     42
# [...]
#9     49
#10    50

df2 <- data.frame(Meter = 41:50+5, Information = rnorm(10))
df2
#   Meter Information
#1     46   0.8155859
#2     47   0.9530017
# [...]
#9     54   0.8817336
#10    55   0.3645192

merge(df1, df2, by = "Meter", all = TRUE)
#   Meter Information
#1     41          NA
#2     42          NA
#3     43          NA
#4     44          NA
#5     45          NA
#6     46   0.8155859
#7     47   0.9530017
#8     48   2.3560323
#9     49  -2.5787036
#10    50   2.8828521
#11    51   0.8408719
#12    52  -0.5162573
#13    53   0.5103627
#14    54   0.8817336
#15    55   0.3645192
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides `merge`, another possible solution is using a combination of `ifelse` and `match`:

```
firstDF$Information <- ifelse(match(firstDF$Meter,secondDF$Meter), secondDF$Information, NA)
```